# Limit consecutive numbers entered into textbox [Calculator App]

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am building a calculator app (it is homework, full disclosure) and have got myself into a bit of a jam. One of the requirements is "make sure that you will not be able to enter more than 9 digits. (i.e., < 1,000,000,000)".

What I'd really like to do is cap off an entered number to 9 digits and make exceptions for operators (+ - * /)

Things I've tried>

- Using RegularExpressionValidator and while I am able to use that to limit the text but it is less than ideal.
- Creating an integer to use as a counter in the code-behind, and have each input that is a digit increase the counter by 1 and each operator reset it to 0. Then, when any digit key is pressed, have it check to see if the Counter >=9 and have it display an alert if so. That was what I was really hoping would work but I had no luck.

My solve method requires that the entire expression (including operators) be in the CurrentInput textbox. If I'm not able to figure this out, I'm going to have to scrap what I'm doing and do it another way. That'd be unfortunate, because I've also built an identical calculator using Javascript and I'd have to re-do that as well. My goof was not thinking through the intended behavior of the calculator before I got this far. From the requirements (linked below), it seems the display boxes only show numbers and keep the current operator in a separate box. I have the current operator displayed as well to the right of the "9" key but also in the display box.

[Requirements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cIbT.jpg)

This is my design, and i've pasted screenshots next to each other to demonstrate its behavior in one continuous operation. 450 divided by 150 = 3 then if an operator is the next entered input, it continues to modify the result so: * 200 + 550 = 1150. If a digit is the next entered input, it sends the result to the top display so: 5 * 5 = 25. I don't really know exactly how a dual display calculator is supposed to work but that's the best I can figure.

[Design&Behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NKU8.jpg)

This is my ASP.Net code:

```
<body>
<form id="CAsp" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server">
            <asp:TableHeaderRow runat="server">
                <asp:TableHeaderCell CssClass="th" ColumnSpan="4" runat="server" Enabled="false">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="Result" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </asp:TableHeaderCell>
            </asp:TableHeaderRow>
            <asp:TableHeaderRow runat="server">
                <asp:TableHeaderCell CssClass="th" ColumnSpan="4" runat="server" Enabled="false">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="CurrentInput" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </asp:TableHeaderCell>
            </asp:TableHeaderRow>
            <asp:TableRow CssClass="toprow" runat="server">
                <asp:TableCell CssClass="topleft" runat="server">
                    <asp:Button ID="Seven" CssClass="smallbutton" runat="server" OnClick="Seven_OnClick" Text="7" /></asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell runat="server">
                    <asp:Button ID="Eight" CssClass="smallbutton" runat="server" OnClick="Eight_OnClick" Text="8" /></asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell runat="server">
                    <asp:Button ID="Nine" CssClass="smallbutton" runat="server" OnClick="Nine_OnClick" Text="9" /></asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell CssClass="topright" runat="server">
                    <asp:Button ID="OP" CssClass="OP" runat="server" Enabled="false" Text="" /></asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableRow runat="server">
                <asp:TableCell runat="server">
                    <asp:Button ID="Four" CssClass="smallbutton" runat="server" OnClick="Four_OnClick" Text="4" /></asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell runat="server">
                    <asp:Button ID="Five" CssClass="smallbutton" runat="server" OnClick="Five_OnClick" Text="5" /></asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell runat="server">
                    <asp:Button ID="Six" CssClass="smallbutton" runat="server" OnClick="Six_OnClick" Text="6" /></asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell runat="server">
                    <asp:Button ID="Clear" CssClass="smallbutton" runat="server" OnClick="Clear_OnClick" Text="C" /></asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableRow runat="server">
                <asp:TableCell runat="server">
                    <asp:Button ID="One" CssClass="smallbutton" runat="server" OnClick="One_OnClick" Text="1" /></asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell runat="server">
                    <asp:Button ID="Two" CssClass="smallbutton" runat="server" OnClick="Two_OnClick" Text="2" /></asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell runat="server">
                    <asp:Button ID="Three" CssClass="smallbutton" runat="server" OnClick="Three_OnClick" Text="3" /></asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell runat="server">
                    <asp:Button ID="Divide" CssClass="smallbutton" runat="server" OnClick="Divide_OnClick" Text="/" /></asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableRow runat="server">
                <asp:TableCell runat="server">
                    <asp:Button ID="Zero" CssClass="smallbutton" runat="server" OnClick="Zero_OnClick" Text="0" /></asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell CssClass="topright" runat="server">
                    <asp:Button ID="Plus" CssClass="smallbutton" runat="server" OnClick="Plus_OnClick" Text="+" /></asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell runat="server">
                    <asp:Button ID="Minus" CssClass="smallbutton" runat="server" OnClick="Minus_OnClick" Text="-" /></asp:TableCell>
                <asp:TableCell runat="server">
                    <asp:Button ID="Multiply" CssClass="smallbutton" runat="server" OnClick="Multiply_OnClick" Text="*" /></asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableRow CssClass="bottomrow" runat="server">
                <asp:TableCell CssClass="bottomcell" ColumnSpan="4" runat="server">
                    <asp:Button ID="Equals" CssClass="longbutton" runat="server" OnClick="Equals_OnClick" Text="=" /></asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
        </asp:Table>
        <div align="center">
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="REV1" runat="server" ForeColor="red" ErrorMessage="Max Characters is 9, Use Backspace" ControlToValidate="CurrentInput" Display="Dynamic" ValidationExpression="^[0-9+-/*\s]{0,9}$" /></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And this is my C# code-behind:

```
public partial class CalcAsp : System.Web.UI.Page
{

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

public void Equals_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string Input = CurrentInput.Text;
        DataTable datatable = new DataTable();
        Object result;
        result = datatable.Compute(Input, null);
        CurrentInput.Text = result.ToString();
        OP.Text = "=";
    }
    catch
    {
        CurrentInput.Text = "Error";
    }
}

protected void Clear_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CurrentInput.Text = "";
    Result.Text = "";
    OP.Text = "";
}

protected void Plus_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (CurrentInput.Text == "")
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Enter A Digit!');", true);
    }
    else
    {
        CurrentInput.Text = CurrentInput.Text + "+";
        OP.Text = "+";
    }
}

protected void Minus_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (CurrentInput.Text == "")
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Enter A Digit!');", true);
    }
    else
    {
        CurrentInput.Text = CurrentInput.Text + "-";
        OP.Text = "-";
    }
}

protected void Multiply_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (CurrentInput.Text == "")
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Enter A Digit!');", true);
    }
    else
    {
        CurrentInput.Text = CurrentInput.Text + "*";
        OP.Text = "*";
    }
}

protected void Divide_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (CurrentInput.Text == "")
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Enter A Digit!');", true);
    }
    else
    {
        CurrentInput.Text = CurrentInput.Text + "/";
        OP.Text = "/";
    }
}

public void Zero_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (OP.Text == "=")
    {
        Result.Text = CurrentInput.Text;
        CurrentInput.Text = "0";
    }
    else
    {
        CurrentInput.Text = CurrentInput.Text + "0";
    }
}

public void One_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (OP.Text == "=")
    {
        Result.Text = CurrentInput.Text;
        CurrentInput.Text = "1";
    }
    else
    {
        CurrentInput.Text = CurrentInput.Text + "1";
    }
}

public void Two_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (OP.Text == "=")
    {
        Result.Text = CurrentInput.Text;
        CurrentInput.Text = "2";
    }
    else
    {
        CurrentInput.Text = CurrentInput.Text + "2";
    }
}

protected void Three_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (OP.Text == "=")
    {
        Result.Text = CurrentInput.Text;
        CurrentInput.Text = "3";
    }
    else
    {
        CurrentInput.Text = CurrentInput.Text + "3";
    }
}

protected void Four_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (OP.Text == "=")
    {
        Result.Text = CurrentInput.Text;
        CurrentInput.Text = "4";
    }
    else
    {
        CurrentInput.Text = CurrentInput.Text + "4";
    }
}

protected void Five_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (OP.Text == "=")
    {
        Result.Text = CurrentInput.Text;
        CurrentInput.Text = "5";
    }
    else
    {
        CurrentInput.Text = CurrentInput.Text + "5";
    }
}

protected void Six_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (OP.Text == "=")
    {
        Result.Text = CurrentInput.Text;
        CurrentInput.Text = "6";
    }
    else
    {
        CurrentInput.Text = CurrentInput.Text + "6";
    }
}

protected void Seven_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (OP.Text == "=")
    {
        Result.Text = CurrentInput.Text;
        CurrentInput.Text = "7";
    }
    else
    {
        CurrentInput.Text = CurrentInput.Text + "7";
    }
}

protected void Eight_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (OP.Text == "=")
    {
        Result.Text = CurrentInput.Text;
        CurrentInput.Text = "8";
    }
    else
    {
        CurrentInput.Text = CurrentInput.Text + "8";
    }
}

protected void Nine_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (OP.Text == "=")
    {
        Result.Text = CurrentInput.Text;
        CurrentInput.Text = "9";
    }
    else
    {
        CurrentInput.Text = CurrentInput.Text + "9";
    }
}

protected void backSpace_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String str = CurrentInput.Text;
    int len;
    len = str.Length;
    CurrentInput.Text = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < len - 1; i++)
    {
        CurrentInput.Text = CurrentInput.Text + Convert.ToString(str[i]);
    }
}
```

}

Thanks for any pointers. I've been reading stackoverflow for years so I think I'm coming in within the community norms on this question, but it is my first post. :)

Comment: Have you considered using JavaScript or jQuery? Is that allowed?

Comment: It is not expressly forbidden but my quibble would be that I had to make two calculators: one with asp.net/c# and one with html/javascript. They are both already built and identical, with the only thing left to do to satisfy the requirements is capping the input to 9 (per the linked requirements). But, if the only way to do this on the asp.net/c# calculator is use another language, then I'll go for it. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: It's not the only solution, but I do believe it would be the best one. ASP.NET would require a postback on every key entered, which is not ideal (except with a validator, I think).

Comment: I will look into it, what javascript technique should I look into?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MaskedEdit Validator` from `AjaxControlToolkit`. It sets pre-defined format for your textbox and prevents user from entering anything other than that. I used this control in one of my project and it works like a charm. The behaviour of the control is rendered in javascript at runtime and it makes a smooth user experience without any postback to server.

For more details - http://www.ajaxcontroltoolkit.com/MaskedEdit/MaskedEdit.aspx

Let me know if you need further help.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would create a method to handle the number clicks. Then alter your insertion code to include a counter of some sort. Something like this might work:

```
protected void InsertNumber(int number)
{
    int numberCount = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < CurrentInput.Text.Length; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Enumberable.Range(0, 9).Contains(Convert.ToInt32(CurrentInput.Text.Substring(i, 1))))
            {
                numberCount++;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            // Do nothing?
        }
    }

    if (numberCount <= 9)
    {
        if (OP.Text == "=")
        {
            Result.Text = CurrentInput.Text;
            CurrentInput.Text = number.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            CurrentInput.Text += number.ToString();
        }
    }
}

// Exacmple usage, apply to all buttons
protected void Nine_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    InsertNumber(9);
}
```

I cannot test at the moment, but it should work.

Comment: This looks really promising but its throwing me an error when compiling: "CS1061: 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox' does not contain a definition for 'Substring' and no extension method 'Substring' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)". Hmm i thought I have the right assemblies. 

"using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Windows.Forms;"

Comment: That's what I get for answering at work. I added `.Text` on line 7 of my code. It should work now.

Comment: Alright it does seem to work at limiting input. When I change "if (numberCount <= 9)" to "<=8" it limits it to 9 digits entered. Then I choose an operator, such as *, and when I enter another digit after that I get "Exception Details: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format." with this line in red: "Line 102:  if (Enumerable.Range(0, 9).Contains(Convert.ToInt32(CurrentInput.Text.Substring(i,1))))" [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/xKhcPn5.png)

Comment: Ah because `*` isn't the right type. Do this: `try { if (Enumerable.Range... // rest of if statement } catch { // Do nothing, or something }`. I've edited my answer. It's dirty and `TryParse` would be better suited, but I'm not in a place to test.